# Double # anchor functionality

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

everyone.

I have menu items that need to be anchored into the specific section using the ID `#section1` so it will scroll down to the portion but the problem is the menu is still there and cannot be close unless I add a link into with `#close`. After the menu items is click and I want to close the menu also. It is possible to use two `#` into a URL? I tried this but it doesn't work.

```html
    <a href="#close#section1"></a>
    <a href="#close/#section1"></a>
```

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71949316/edit) to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'close the menu'? Does it become (?go back to?) a hamburger icon being displayed for example?

Comment: itoggle/ hide mo Yung menu onclick sa jQuery. Tpos a name to scroll or scrolltop sa specific div. Hope this helps ;)